# global $sitepress is null

Tags: wordpress, symfony

I'm using the Symfony command component to do a task of importing data into the Wordpress tables. I use the global $ sitepress to insert translations with the WPML plugin, but $ sitepress remains desperately NULL.

```
/* ... */
public function export()
    {

            require_once(__DIR__.
                         '/../../../../web/wp/wp-load.php'
            );

           global $sitepress;
           var_dump($sitepress);

           /* ... */
    }
```

I don't understand why this global is NULL

Answer (score 0):

**wpml-api.php** basically contains a number of functions for you to use. It doesn't have the $sitepress variable itself. Normally you don't want to include functions inside your function. You should include these files outside of the function. Then in your function, you can try to do

```
global $sitepress;
```

Then do a **var_dump** see if you get it. However if you going to use these api functions directly, you don't need to do the *global* declaration as the API functions are already doing that.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I forgot to put the global inside my function. But $sitepress is NULL

Comment: WPML plugin is hooked into WordPress. I don't suppose you can simply pull it out on its own since it uses WordPress functions. The $sitepress variable is instantiated in sitepress.php and the class itself is define in sitepress.class.php, both under plugin root directory. But like I said, you probably can't use the variable on its own without loading WordPress.

Comment: Hey, I have solved the problem. When the command was launched, the some server globals was called : WP wasn't instantiated but no exception was generated. I fix this problem in the `wp-config.php`

Comment: @Toutma What fix you did in wp-config.php file?